# phonegap 2.2.0 plugins for native android transitions

Tags: android, cordova

I am building a native app and i don't want to use Jquery Mobile because when new pages are loaded with transitions, the Javascript in the new page don't work.
Is there any phonegap plugin which can enable native page transitions ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you are using PhoneGap you are not making a native application, you are making a hybrid application.

Using PhoneGap can you use native page transitions? Short answer is no. But if you are using JQuery Mobile you can use their page transitions:

```
<a href="yourPage.html" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="fade" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">dialog</span></span></a>
```

The key here is ****data-transition="fade"****

Check out all of JQuery Mobile Page transitions here:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

Comment: There is this phonegap plugin now available...http://ilee.co.uk/native-page-transitions-with-phonegap/